# Where can audio resources of an app be stored at?

Tags: applications

I have a copy of the package "com.rdsg.goofymemes", a 21st-century humor soundboard (you can find it [here](https://goofy-ahh-soundboard-memes.en.uptodown.com/android).)

For weeks, I have been on a mission to retrieve audio files from this soundboard, but they are nowhere to be seen.

Usually, they are in /res/raw but inside of this folder is "firebase_common_keep.xml".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@string/google_app_id,@string/gcm_defaultSenderId,@string/google_api_key,@string/firebase_database_url,@string/ga_trackingId,@string/google_storage_bucket,@string/project_id" />
```

I can launch the app and play sounds without having WI-FI on, so the audio resources must not be loaded from the internet.
I have tried searching for different extensions (mp3, wav, ogg, flac and so on) but still cannot find the audio files.

So I plugged a rooted phone into my computer and downloaded the app. I have then looked at the private app directory (data/data/com.rdsg.goofymemes/) and still can't find nothing.

(I used JADX to extract the source code.)

Comment: Look into assets/bin/data. There exists a UNITY3d file and a RESOURCES file with considerable sizes. Probably, one or both of these files contains the assets you are looking for. That said, I cannot confirm this because I'm unable to open these files. Some dedicated tool might be needed to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Firelord said, there is a unity3d file located in assets/bin/data.
After some digging, I found AssetStudio, a Windows program that can open assets (in my case a unity3d file).

Some assets failed to load, and some, upon selection (which triggers preview) crashed the app, but I got around it.